# Add device objects to the Azure group in Powershell foreach

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run a simple Powershell command let, which is listing all devices matching name criteria and in the next step is moving these devices to a select Azure group.

I tried with:

```
$result = Get-AzureADDevice -All $True -SearchString "LAP-BK" | ForEach-Object -Process {Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "25f94620-d850-4ec6-9476-050429d44926" -RefObjectId "$result.ObjectId"}
```

but that throwing errors. I also tried with

```
$result = Get-AzureADDevice -All $True -SearchString "LAP-BK" |Select-Object ObjectId
forEach ($item in $result)
{
 
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "25f94620-d850-4ec6-9476-050429d44926" -RefObjectId "$item"
}
exit
```

The error are various, the last one I get was:

```
Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Invalid object identifier ' @{ObjectId=debb95af-9h1f-49d6-ad84-8438f9c99b10}'. RequestId: 6df36830-7708-4f6b-b836-cd065f5f60b1
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error message(s) :)

Comment: In the last example, change `-RefObjectId "$item"` to `-RefObjectId $item.ObjectId`

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to figure out the error from my end by running your script line by line, and I was able to find exactly where it was occurring:*

*Referring to [Jamesyumnam article](https://jamesyumnam.com/2021/06/18/powershell-script-to-add-devices-to-azure-ad-group-with-and-without-object-ids/), I was able to successfully create and run the below script.*

```
$groupName = "<groupName>"
Connect-AzureAD
$groupObject = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $groupName
$outcome = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString "xxxxxx" | select-object objectID
try{
foreach ($item in $outcome)
{
 $deviceObj = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString $item.DeviceName
 Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupObject.ObjectId -RefObjectId $item.ObjectId
 }
 }
 catch {
   Write-Host "Device not existed"
}
```

*Executed in Azure PowerShell:*

[image]

***Member added in Azure Portal:***

[image]

***Note***: *It will be more helpful if you include `try{} catch{}` blocks in your code to find these kinds of blockers.*